# jQuery setInterval with different times

Tags: jquery

I am trying to something like this:

```
var time = 2000;
var counter = 0;
var looper = setInterval(function () {

                if(counter == 0){

                        time = 5000;

                }else if(counter == 1){

                        time = 10000;

                }
                counter++;

            }, time);
```

When my counter is a certain number, then I want the timer time to be different, the following I have tried does not work :) my timer stays at 2000, what am I doing wrong, or is what I am trying to do not possible?

Comment: Use `setTimeout` instead, and keep re-setting it in the function.

Comment: Something like that : http://jsfiddle.net/ob9rfc52/

Comment: **I made a code with you need. See http://jsfiddle.net/rogeriodemoraes/sxg3k4m2/**